# PHP timezone ahead or behind?

Tags: php

I have searched on Google and read some of the PHP manuals on timezone and offsets but seem can't find the answer to this question!

So I'm going to ask it here. please let me know if this is a duplicated question or has an answer else where and  i will delete it.

Currently, I am using the code bellow to show the time difference between two locations in PHP.

The code works fine But there is an issue. if the 2location first" is behind the "location two", the result will be shown with a minus before the number.

For example: if the first location is New York and the second one is London the time difference will be shown as -5.

And if it was the other way round, i.e. London first and the New York second it will be shown as 5.

What I need to do is to show the time difference like this:

london is 5 hours "ahead" of New York.

or

New York is 5 hours "behind" of london.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //be sure to validate and clean your variables
    $timezone1 = htmlentities($_POST['timezone1']);
    $timezone2 = htmlentities($_POST['timezone2']);

    //then you can use them in a PHP function. 
    function get_timezone_offset( $origin_tz, $remote_tz ) {
    $timezone1 = new DateTimeZone( $origin_tz );
    $timezone2 = new DateTimeZone( $remote_tz );

    $datetime1 = new DateTime("now", $timezone1);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime("now", $timezone2);

    $offset = $timezone1->getOffset($datetime1) - $timezone2->getOffset($datetime2);
    return $offset;
    
}

$offset = get_timezone_offset($timezone1, $timezone2);

}

?>
```

and here i echo the result:

```
<?php echo $offset/3600; ?>
```

and this the HTML dropdown list of locations:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" class="myForm" method="post" action="">
  <select name="timezone2" id="timezone2" class="timezone2">
    <optgroup label="Africa">
                        <?php
                    foreach($options as $key => $value)
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'. $key .'" label="'. $value .'">'.$value.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
<option value="Africa/Abidjan" label="Abidjan">Abidjan</option>
<option value="Africa/Accra" label="Accra">Accra</option>
<option value="Africa/Addis_Ababa" label="Addis Ababa">Addis Ababa</option>
<option value="Africa/Algiers" label="Algiers">Algiers</option>
<option value="Africa/Asmara" label="Asmara">Asmara</option>


</optgroup>
</select>
```

The timezone1 and timezone2 dropdownlists are identical by the way.

Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: It's not that clear from your code what your actually trying to do, are you getting the user time zone or PHP time zone, as you've said both?

Comment: @Lissy, I am getting PHP timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually a problem of simple logic. Use an if() statement and specify the appropriate text to be echoed based on the offset value.

```
$str = '';
if (0 > $offset)
{
   // For negative offset (hours behind)
   $hour_diff = $offset / 3600 * -1;
   $str = "{$hour_diff} hour(s) behind of";
}
elseif (0 < $offset)
{
   // For positive offset (hours ahead)
   $hour_diff = $offset / 3600;
   $str = "{$hour_diff} hour(s) ahead of";
}
else
{
   // Have you considered the case of same timezone?
   $str = "in the same timezone as";
}

echo "{$location1} is {$str} {$location2}";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Greenwich Mean Time** 
Well if your using time(), it's in GMT as it is the Unix timestamp that's been counting seconds since the Unix Epoch  (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Answer (score 0):

### Idea

Use can use the sign of you `$offset` to determine the string to display:

- Positive: A ahead of B ;
- Negative: A behind B ;
- Zero: same.

### Code

```
function tzPosition( $number ) {
    return ( $number > 0 ) ? 'ahead' : ( ( $number < 0 ) ? 'behind' : 'same' );
} 
echo sprintf("%s is %s hours %s of %s", $cityA, abs($offset), tzPosition($offset), $cityB);
```

### References

- [`gmp_sign`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-sign.php)

Comment: Your code will produce "SF is 0 hours same of LA" (case of same timezone).

Comment: @Sutandiono yep, it's not a out-of-box solution, it give the idea. User will probably adapt to its need

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the sign of the result, you can do this: `<?php echo $offset/3600*-1; ?>`

If you only want to remove the minus `<?php echo ($offset < 0) ? $offset/3600*-1 : $offset; ?>`

If you are going to remove the sign to write the sentence you can do this:

```
<?php
//check direction
$direction = ($offset < 0)? "ahead" : "behind";
$direction = ($offset === 0)? "same timezone as" : $direction;
//remove the -
$hours = $offset/3600;
$hours = ($offset < 0) ? $hours*-1 : $hours;
//Get the cities from the Timezone
preg_match('#.*/([^/]+$)#',$timezone1,$city1);
preg_match('#.*/([^/]+$)#',$timezone2,$city2);
//echo sentence replacing underscores with spaces.
echo str_replace("_", " ", $city2[1]).' is '.$hours.' hours '.$direction.' '.str_replace("_", " ", $city1[1]);
?>
```

I think this should work with the code you provided in the question.

Comment: I had not considered same timezone, I have just read it in the answer from @Sutandiono. I have just added something for that option.

Comment: This sort of works BUT it echo's the result like this: New York is 18000 hours behind London. the time difference between london and new york is only 5 hours! do you know why this is happening?

Comment: also, it shows London is 32400 hours behind Sydney!! this is wired!

Comment: Sorry. I have made a correction to the code, I forgot to make the conversion from seconds to hours in the condition.